# How can i remove an element from an array according to user input?

Tags: java

Newbie here. Basically, I want to remove
a chosen element by the user from an array.

but I do not know how to remove it in the first place.
Here's the code.

```java
 static void TeamFunction() {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int teamNo;
        System.out.println("-----Teams------");
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Number of teams '(max-4)' and '(min-2)' ");
            teamNo = scan.nextInt();
        } while (teamNo > 4 || teamNo == 1);

        String[] teamName = new String[teamNo];
        int[] teamScore = new int[teamNo];
        String[] Tevent = new String[5];
        int teamRank;
        int eventNo = 5;
// condition check for number of teams
        // skip all of team code if 0

        if (teamNo == 0) {
            System.out.println("--Skipped-Teams--");
        } else {
            // event names
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter Event Name " + (i + 1) + " for the teams");
                Tevent[i] = scan.next();
            }
// name and rank of the teams

            for (int i = 0; i < teamNo; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter Name of team " + (i + 1));
                teamName[i] = scan.next();
            }

            for (int a = 0; a < eventNo; a++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < teamNo; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter rank of the team " + (teamName[i]) + " on the event " + (a + 1));
                    teamRank = scan.nextInt();
                    int tRank = 0;
                    // scoring system for the teams
                    switch (teamRank) {
                        case 3:
                            tRank = 5;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            tRank = 10;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            tRank = 20;
                            break;
                    }
                    if (teamRank == 0 || teamRank >= 4) {
                        System.out.println("The team will not be awarded points");
                    } else {
                        teamScore[i] += tRank;
                        System.out.println(tRank + " points is granted for this event\n");
                    }

                    if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                        scan.nextLine();
                    }
                }
                int topTScore = 0; // this will be used to find the highest value score
                int topteam = -1; // and this will be the index of the team
                for (int i = 0; i < teamNo; i++) {
                    if (teamScore[i] > topTScore) {
                        topTScore = teamScore[i]; // the highest score (up to now)
                        topteam = i; // save the team number for the one with the highest score
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(teamName[topteam] + " is the winner, with a score of " + topTScore+"\n");

                System.out.println("Enter the team number who you wish to remove after event 1\n");
                if (teamNo == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Team 1 is 0");
                    System.out.println("Team 2 is 1\n");
                }
                if (teamNo == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Team 1 is 0");
                    System.out.println("Team 2 is 1");
                    System.out.println("Team 3 is 2\n");
                }
                if (teamNo ==4) {
                    System.out.println("Team 1 is 0");
                    System.out.println("Team 2 is 1");
                    System.out.println("Team 3 is 2");
                    System.out.println("Team 4 is 3\n");
                }

                int removeIndex = scan.nextInt();

// and remove the element that the user entered. <--- this is the one . i dont know where to start.
                
                }
            }
```

Comment: you can't. you can blank it out (replace it with a default value) or create a new array, without that value, but you can't "delete" an element, as arrays have fixed sizes

Answer (score 1):

You're using an array with primitive type `int`. Arrays in java don't provide a remove function. This means that the only way to truly delete an element without just setting the element to something like -1 or 0 is to create a new array and copy the associated data over.

You might also want to check out `ArrayList`s instead because that has a remove function that lets you remove at an index.